# jQuery Detect Video Exit Full Screen Then Do Something

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a video which plays when I press a button. After the video finishes, my jQuery code changes some things on the webpage. I need my jQuery to detect when the user plays the video and exits full screen.

Something like this:

- Video is playing.
- User exits video.
- jQuery detects this and runs method.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can hook to the `fullscreenchange` event and check the state of the video with the `fullScreen` property. Note that you will need to use some browser-specific properties to achieve this too. Try this:

```
$('#myVideo').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var isFullScreen = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;

    // work with the state flag here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

but i think it just work on chrome.

```
$(document).on('webkitExitFullScreen', function()      {       
  alert("Full Screen Closed"); 
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.